# SQL join or what?

Tags: sql, join, nested, statements

I'm an SQL newbie. sorry.
i have 3 tables: services, cities, city_services. i need to get all services that are available in a given city (using city_id) from the city_services table, but also want to grab the service name from the service table - all in one statement. I know i can nest 2 statements and 2 while loops (php) but that seems inefficient.

Do i need a JOIN or a nested sql statement? i Can't wrap my head around this.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be great!

Thanks.

sndwg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use a join. For example:

```
SELECT service.name, city_service.id
FROM City_Services AS city_service
INNER JOIN Services As service ON city_service.service_id = service.service_id
WHERE city_service.city_id = ?
```

(How you specify the `city_id` will depend on your database and how you're accessing it. In the above example I'm assuming you're using a parameterized query with unnamed parameters.)

Comment: hi thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I didnt know you could use a where clause with a Join, as none of the examples on the internet show that....
this query did the trick...

    SELECT a.service_id, b.service_name
    FROM city_services AS a
    INNER JOIN services As b ON a.service_id = b.service_id
    WHERE a.city_id = x